# Avast telling my unity game as a suspicious file

Tags: unity-game-engine, antivirus

I developed an android game using unity game engine. Whenever the game is installed Avast says  "Suspicious file detected cloud reputation [Susp]" Do you know what could be the problem? And does this problem also comes when the app is installed from Google play store.

Comment: that just tells you that antivirus tools are overzealous and overly cautious (they sell themselves by supposedly making the user feel safe yet what they actually do is to make the user feel potentially threatened to justify their own existence - a truly good virus scanner keeps quiet unless there is an actual threat). Typically you'll find an option to turn of monitoring of so-called "suspicious" apps or behavior.

Comment: plz report it..  https://feedback.avast.com/responses/custom-application-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are developing the game, you are probably the one and only person with that particular file. Therefore it has low reputation (Avast haven't seen it before). They may be blocking every unknown executable.